# I accidently deleted the Apple submission certificate in the Keychain

Tags: ios, code-signing

I accidentally deleted the Apple submission certificate in the Keychain, now whenever I run the app, it gives me this warning:
Application failed codesign verification.  The signature was invalid, or it was not signed with an Apple submission certificate. (-19011)

How can I fix it?  Thanks!

Comment: It ends up being my provisioning problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Log into the provisioning portal and download it again.

Comment: I downloaded the provisions, but I couldn't find the certificate for Apple submission certificate...

Comment: Look under Certificates --> Distribution